# Pegar os dados dentro da div e depois imprimir na tela em pdf(algum método)?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<div id='titulo'><h1>CheckList </h1></div>\n
<h2>Credito linha </h2>
Proposta PVE: <input type=\"text\" id=\"proposta\" size=\"80\" maxlength=\"100\" value=\" \" style=\"align-content:center\" /></br></br>
Veiculo zero Km:<input type=\"radio\"  name=\"veiculo\" id=\"opcao\" value=\"sim\">Sim
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"veiculo\" id=\"opcao\" value=\"não\">Não
</br></br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>S/N</th>
        <th>Item verificado</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspImagem NFe legível?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"2\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspNFe validada no site</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"3\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspImagem Documento legivel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"4\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspDados corretos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"5\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspDados do veículo: marca, modelo,versão, ano fabricação/modelo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"6\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspConta informada para crédito pertence ao vendedor do veiculo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"7\" >Sim</td>
        <td>&nbspDocumentos de validação</td>
    </tr>
</table></br>
Observações:</br>
<textarea id=\"mobile\"></textarea></br></br>
</form>
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn-padrao\" button=\"imprimir\">


</br></br></br></br>
```

Comment: Olá Thiago, queres gerar um PDF é isso? que linguagem tens no servidor?

Comment: tenho mas eu quero que imprime na tela msm sem envio de algo para o servidor, o usuario marca as opçoes e depois imprime ou gere pdf com as opções marcadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o pdf você pode usar [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) é uma boa solução para gerar arquivos em pdf, para enviar os dados, você coloca o seu formulário para submeter para uma página que vai receber os dados e gerar o pdf

Comment: Bom achei interessante mas será que vai pegar os dados a medida que eu clico e imprimi as funções marcadas mostrando todo o formulário?

Comment: Aí vai depender da forma que você enviar as informações para o php gerar o pdf. Outra alternativa seria usar o [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)